# Is it possible to determine the type of instance for an AWS RDS MySQL instance from within MySQL?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I would like to know if it is possible for me to determine the instance type and storage available from the MySQL command line while connected to the RDS server.

I have a project where the database efficiency degraded horribly as soon as I switched from querying my dedicated development server's MySQL database to the client's AWS RDS instance (located in the same availability zone as the EC2 instance hosting the web application). The difference being that the EC2 instance is in North America, the development server is in South Africa, and despite traversing the Atlantic ocean, the RDS instance was still approximately 55% slower on intensive queries.

Because the infrastructure is being hosted by a third-party managed hosting service provider, I cannot directly ask the service provider what instance type they've deployed. The only access rights I have are basic grant, create, select, update, insert. I cannot access the AWS Management Console.

Assuming it's possible, could someone please give me some guidance on what command(s) to run to determine this?

Comment: Just ask your client.

Comment: @EEAA I have. They haven't been told either

Comment: Then they are giving their money to the wrong third party provider. Which I know isn't helpful for *you*, but still...unbelievable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't possible to determine the instance type, available storage, or any similar properties of an RDS instance from "within" MySQL (*within* meaning via the SQL interface, which is the only exposed interface on RDS -- there's no shell/OS access).

The only way to learn these things or to examine the performance metrics is with access to the AWS account via the AWS console or API.

Answer (score 0):

There is one hint, which might be usable. You can query the max parallel connections in MySQL with `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";`.

AWS tells in their [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html#RDS_Limits.MaxConnections) that the default "max_connections"-limit is calculated from the memory/ram of the instance.

The calculation for MySQL is `{DBInstanceClassMemory/12582880}` - so max_connections multiplied with 12582880 gives you the amount of memory for the instance.

Example: An instance has 639 max_connections - that leads to 8,040,460,320 bytes or 8GB of memory. Now you need to have a table of all instances, for example from [here](https://instances.vantage.sh/rds/). From that, we know now, that the instance must be one of the ones ending in "large", like "db.m5.large".

Of course thats not exactly the instance, but it gives you an idea what instance-type is used.

Please be aware, that `max_connections` can be changed from the aws-user.